# Reflection subclass of generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

In following scenario:

```
public class A<T> { }

public class B : A<AClass> { }
```

Is is possible to determine if B is a subclass of A without specifying AClass (the generic parameter)? As in:

```
typeof(B).IsSubclassOf(A<>)
```

Comment: Neither the code nor the question make sense to me. That code won't compile, so asking what reflection does is a non-starter.

Comment: A generic class and anything that inherits from it needs a type parameter (i.e. `T`) either implicitly or explicitly. As far as I know you can't get around that by subclassing. Trying to do so doesn't even really make sense. Can you explain your goals better?

Comment: How could `B` possibly be a subclass of `A` when you are defining `B` as inheriting from `A<T>`, and `A<T>` is not derived from any other class?

Comment: @EricLippert Fixed the code and added more information.

Comment: @Yuck Thanks for noticing. I fixed that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes but you'll have to go through the hierarchy yourself:

```
var instance = new B();
Type t = instance.GetType();

bool isA = false;
while(t != typeof(object))
{
    if(t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(A<>))
    {
        isA = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        t = t.BaseType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works and also verifies the entire inheritance hierarchy, not only the base type (I was thinking only about the base type). Thanks!

Comment: Won't this cause an infinite loop when the type does not have the generic in its hierarchy?

Comment: @TheBoxyBear - It just checks the entire base class hierarchy and should exit the loop when it reaches the bottom (object).

Comment: Right, when it reaches the end of the hierarchy, t will be System.Object and the loop condition will be false.

Answer (score 1):

**@Lee** answer is good for search in whole full base class **hierarchy**.

If someone need to determine if subclass inherits from **single** generic subclass `A<T>`

```
Type t = typeof(B);
bool isSubClass = t.BaseType.IsGenericType && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefination() == typeof(A<>);
```

**Extension method can be used:**

```
public static bool IsSubClassOfEx(Type t, Type baseType)
{
  return t.BaseType.IsGenericType && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == baseType;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a simple way to do this: `if (B.GetType().BaseType.Name == typeof(A<>).Name)`

Comment: Two problems: 1) this "solves" only the immediate-base-class scenario, rather than the more general any-base-class scenario, and 2) the `Name` property is not a unique identifier for a type. Indeed, even the fully-qualified `FullName` property is not, in certain corner cases. This is not a useful answer, especially given that there is in fact already a correct answer to the question here.